# Swift: How to fill a ScrollView from Interface Builder with UIViews programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

I am working on a project where I want the user to be able to select two methods of input for the same form. I came up with a scrollview that contains two custom UIViews (made programmatically). Here is the code for the responsible view controller:

```
import UIKit

class MainVC: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    
    var customView1: CustomView1 = CustomView1()
    
    var customView2: customView2 = CustomView2()
    
    var frame = CGRect.zero
    
    func setupScrollView() {

        pageControl.numberOfPages = 2
        
        frame.origin.x = 0
        frame.size = scrollView.frame.size
        
        customView1 = customView1(frame: frame)

        self.scrollView.addSubview(customView1)
        
        frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width
        frame.size = scrollView.frame.size
        
        customView2 = CustomView2(frame: frame)
        
        self.scrollView.addSubview(customView2)
        
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.width * 2, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
        
        self.scrollView.delegate = self
        
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageNumber = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupScrollView()
        
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }
```

While it works, Xcode gives me an error message for auto layout:

> Scrollable content size is ambiguous for "ScrollView"

Also a problem: content on the second UIView is not centered, even though it should be:

[picture of the not centered content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1fwZ.png)

```
import UIKit

class customView2: UIView {

lazy var datePicker: UIDatePicker = {
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return datePicker
  }()

//initWithFrame to init view from code
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupView()
}
  
//initWithCode to init view from xib or storyboard
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}

func setupView () {
    self.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
    
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.datePickerValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    
    addSubview(datePicker)
    
    setupLayout()
}

func setupLayout() {
    
    let view = self
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        datePicker.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        datePicker.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 20),
        datePicker.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
        datePicker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2)
    ])
}

@objc func datePickerValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    let selectedDate: String = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
    print("Selected value \(selectedDate)")
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? Thank you very much in advance. And please go easy on me, this is my first question on stackoverflow. I am also fairly new to programming in swift.

Comment: 1) An empty scroll view in Storyboard / Interface Builder will always show *Scrollable content size is ambiguous for "ScrollView"* - because you haven't put anything there for its content. 2) When you add `customView1` and `customView2` views to the scroll view, use auto-layout constraints... the view frames are not yet set in `viewDidLoad()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make things easier on yourself,

- add a horizontal `UIStackView` to the scroll view
- set `.distribution = .fillEqually`
- constrain all 4 sides to the scroll view's `.contentLayoutGuide`
- constrain its height to the scroll view's `.frameLayoutGuide`
- add your custom views to the stack view
- constrain the width of the **first** custom view to the width of the scroll view's `.frameLayoutGuide`

Here is your code, modified with that approach:

```
class MainVC: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    
    var customView1: CustomView1 = CustomView1()
    
    var customView2: CustomView2 = CustomView2()
    
    func setupScrollView() {
        
        pageControl.numberOfPages = 2
        
        // let's put the two custom views in a horizontal stack view
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.axis = .horizontal
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        stack.addArrangedSubview(customView1)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(customView2)
        
        // add the stack view to the scroll view
        scrollView.addSubview(stack)
        
        let contentG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let frameG = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain stack view to all 4 sides of content layout guide
            stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.topAnchor),
            stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.leadingAnchor),
            stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.trailingAnchor),
            stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.bottomAnchor),

            // stack view Height equal to scroll view frame layout guide height
            stack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.heightAnchor),
            
            // stack is set to fillEqually, so we only need to set
            //  width of first custom view equal to scroll view frame layout guide width
            customView1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.widthAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        self.scrollView.delegate = self
        
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let pageNumber = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupScrollView()
        
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

Couple additional notes...

1. `UIScrollView` layout ambiguity.

As I said in my initial comment, if we add a `UIScrollView` in Storyboard / **I**nterface **B**uilder, but do ***NOT*** give it any constrained content, IB will complain that it has *Scrollable Content Size Ambiguity* -- because it ***does***. We haven't told IB what the content will be.

We can either ignore it, or select the scroll view and, at the bottom of the Size Inspector pane, change `Ambiguity` to `Never Verify`.

As a general rule, you should correct all auto-layout warnings / errors, but in specific cases such as this - where we ***know*** that it's setup how we want, and we'll be satisfying constraints at run-time - it doesn't hurt to leave it alone.

2. `UIDatePicker` not being centered horizontally.

It actually **is** centered. If you add this line:

```
datePicker.backgroundColor = .green
```

You'll see that the object frame itself is centered, but the UI elements inside the frame are left-aligned:

[image]

From quick research, it doesn't appear that can be changed.

Now, from Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker), we see:

> You should integrate date pickers in your layout using Auto Layout. Although date pickers can be resized, they should be used at their intrinsic content size.

Curiously, if we add a `UIDatePicker` in Storyboard, change its `Preferred Style` to `Compact`, and give it centerX and centerY constraints... Storyboard doesn't believe it has an intrinsic content size.

If we add it via code, giving it only X/Y position constraints, it will show up where we want it at its *intrinsic content size*. But... if we jump into `Debug View Hierarchy`, Xcode tells us its *Position and size are ambiguous.*

Now, what's even more fun...

Tap that control and watch the Debug console fill with ***535 Lines of auto-layout errors / warnings!!!***

Some quick investigation -- these are all **internal** auto-layout issues, and have nothing to do with our code or layout.

We see similar issues with the iOS built-in keyboard when it starts showing auto-complete options.

Those are safe to ignore.

Comment: Great suggestion, I will try this and let you know how it works out! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Works equally well and the code is a lot cleaner. The DatePicker still is not centered though, but this is probably a deeper issue, as I get a whole list of console errors about the DatePicker constraints. I will look at it tomorrow, I think.

Comment: The error message about the amiguous scrollview size is still there, but I think it's safe to ignore?

Comment: @RickDeckard - sorry, I missed the cause of that issue. See the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: Wow, great work! Thank you so much for your help! I was also slightly surprised to see the many lines of errors in the console that came up with the DatePicker, but your investigation is really helpful. You probably saved me hours of work.

Comment: I found out, why the DatePicker did not seem to be centered. I had a width-constraint in place, that was set to half of the superview. As the width seems to be fixed, it made it behave the way it did. I removed the constraint and now it appears where I expected it.